# Gray out mat form input field- Angular

Tags: input, field, mat

Below is my code. The division field is readonly. Am not able to disable as it is Reactive forms.
Please help how to achieve this.
I need to display the division field in gray color.appearance ="fill" changes the design view.

```
 <mat-form-field   appearance="outline" class="form-group">
                                    <mat-label >Division</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput type="text"   name="upd" [(ngModel)]="formAssess.upd"
                                        placeholder="Division" [matTooltip]="formAssess.upd"
                                        matTooltipPosition="above" [readonly]="readOnlyValue" > 
                                </mat-form-field>
```